# Retain the same navigation bar and tab bar on clicking a navigation item and moving to a different view

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

[image: Storyboard]

Following is my Main.storyboard.

I have a Tab bar controller that is embedded in a Navigation controller.

On clicking different items in the Tab bar the Navigation bar remains the same throughout .

On click of different items in the Navigation bar I want the the View controller to retain the same functionality.

i.e On Clicking the message icon in the navigation bar , when the user moves to a different view I want the navigation bar to be the same as in the Tab bar controller .

I also want this view to have the same tab bar in it.

Right now the problem is when I click on the item in the navigation bar, I segue to a view where the navigation bar has only the back button and there is no tab bar.

How can I make sure that this view has the same navigation bar and the tab bar?

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: You may have to rethink your approach a bit. You are asking one navigationController to control another. Either the control in the navigationbar will have to navigate to a controller that is actually part of the tabbar, and thus available through the more-button, or you must completely design your own navigation component which will allow your tabbar to have buttons in the navbar.